# Sending messages between modules

Tags: elm

Can't quite figure out how to go about sending messages between modules when working with reusable components.

I have an expanding text area that I'd like to use on a number of different sections on a site. The Text Area accepts a portion of HTML that makes up the user actions. Typically handling submit, cancel, upload icons, etc..

Tried to write up a quick example of what I'm talking about without throwing a ton of code on here. So essentially, I'd like to just plug and play peices of HTML that are already attached.

I'm assuming CancelNote is getting fired as a TextArea msg, so it never sees a Cancel Note msg. Not sure how I would use Html.map here (or even if I would).....feel like plug and play method is probably a bad approach, but not sure how else I could achieve decent reusability .

```
SEPERATE MODULE

update model msg =
    case msg of
        CancelText ->
            ( { model | note = (Just "") }
            , Cmd.none
            )


view: stuff
view stuff = 
......
    TextArea.view 
         (button [ Html.Events.onClick CancelText] [])






TEXT AREA MODULE 


view : Html.Html msg -> Html msg
view actionHtml =
    div [ class "extended_text_area_container" ] [
        textarea [] [
        ]
        , actionHtml
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages are just values like any other. You can pass them around directly:

```
-- SEPERATE MODULE


view: stuff
view stuff = 
......
    TextArea.view CancelText



-- TEXT AREA MODULE 


view : msg -> Html msg
view msg =
    div [ class "extended_text_area_container" ]
        [ textarea [] []
        , button [ onClick msg ] []
        ]
```

Edit: If you need to also maintain internal state, just use another message to tell the parent to update the state:

```
-- Main module


type msg =
    ...
    SetTextAreaState TextArea.state


update model msg =
    case msg of
        ...
        SetTextAreaState state ->
            { model | textAreaState = state }


view : Model -> Html msg
    TextArea.view SetTextAreaState model.textAreaState



-- TextArea module

type State =
    ...

type Msg =
    Clicked


update : State -> Msg -> State
update state msg =
    case msg of
        Clicked ->
            { state | clicked = True }


view : (State -> msg) -> State -> Html msg
view toMsg state =
    let
        updateAndWrap msg =
            toMsg (update state msg)
    in
    div [ class "extended_text_area_container" ]
        [ textarea [] []
        , button [ onClick (updateAndWrap Clicked) ] []
        ]
```

Here, instead of passing a `msg` to `onClick` directly in `TextArea.view`, call a function that updates the state and then wraps it in the `msg` constructor passed in from the parent, which will produce a message of a type that we don't know anything about.

Also, while I use an internal `Msg` type and `update` function similarly to the overall Elm architecture, that is in no way mandatory. It's just a nice way of doing it since it's familiar and scales well.

Comment: Thanks. To provide a bit more clarity, the issue is if I have different messages being managed in the textarea. 

Let's say I have a TextAreaMessage type defined with a  "HideArea" message.  And a button that calls it on click. My View method would have complain that it's returning both a TextAreaMessage and an Html msg. 

The only way I can think to manage it would be using an Html.map to transform the message back to the original after the TextArea is finished updating it's settings. But I feel like this isn't the correct approach.

Comment: I've updated the answer. The message passing is exactly the same, it's just a different message. But you have to do a bit more with it in the "component".

Comment: This design comes from https://github.com/evancz/elm-sortable-table, which isn't quite up to date, but provides a real example of it in use and some more explanation.